# Do I have to use npgsql for a project on prosgresql, EF Core and .net Core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.0

I am starting a project with prosgresql, EF Core and .net Core. For this case is it a must to use npgsql?

Comment: I'd say yes, if you want to go with an open source solution. There are other commercial providers, like Devart dotConnect. I have had good experiences with that latter product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isnt a must to use npgsql you can use EF Core on its own https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html.

However I would recommend using npgsql apposed to EFCORE, I use it for when working with .NET CORE and PostgresSQL they also have great documentation at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html and you don't need to depend on EF